# NULL changes to 0 when added to the db

Tags: php, sql

Ok I have tried everything I can think of, I couldn't make it. I am creating some inputs like this:

```
for($l = 1; $l <= 6; $l++){
            echo '<div class="col-sm-auto" style="text-align:center;">
                <h4>QTY'.$l.'</h4>
                <input class="divtop" name="qt'.$l.$count.'" type="number" value="'.${'quantity'.$l}.'"  style="width:85px; text-align:center;" />
                <h4 style="margin-top:10px;">PRICE '.$l.'</h4>
                <input class="divtop" name="price'.$l.$count.'" step="0.01" type="number" value="'.${'prize'.$l}.'"  style="width:55px; text-align:center;" />
            </div>';
        }
```

And then when I get the $_POST I am checking if the input is 0 or "" and setting it to NULL.

```
for($z = 1; $z <= 6; $z++){
    ${'qty'.$z} = $_POST["qty".$z.$i];
    ${'price'.$z} = $_POST["timi".$z.$i]; 
    if( ${'timi'.$z} == 0 || ${'timi'.$z} == ""){ ${'timi'.$z} = NULL; }
    if( ${'qty'.$z} == 0 || ${'qty'.$z} == ""){ ${'qty'.$z} = NULL; }
}
```

And I am adding to the DB with this

```
$priceupdate = $conn ->query("UPDATE table SET qty1 = '$qty1',  qty2 = '$qty2',  qty3 = '$qty3',  qty4 = '$qty4', qty5 = '$qty5',  qty6 = '$qty6' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

But when the query runs, qty6 (for example) that is 0 or "" doesn't insert as NULL in the DB but as 0, the table field is int (though it doesn't really matter). Any ideas how to fix this? I am kinda stuck! [image]

I have tried (qty6 = $var) the query just stops there.

The structure does allow NULL as the default value is in fact NULL.

If I try ${'qty'.$z} = 'NULL' ; this makes NULL a string so it wouldn't help as the field value type for price is Float and for qty is Integer

Comment: With the string quotes/php concat (qty6 = '$var') you end up inserting string('') (qty6 = '' instead of qty6 = NULL) which gets implicitly converted to int(0). Try using prepared statements without the quotes.

Comment: What is your table structure?  Maybe the column does not allow nulls so when you insert it, it converts to a 0?

Comment: it does as the default value is NULL check the columns 12-15

Comment: `${'timi'.$z} = 'NULL' ;` ... `${'qty'.$z} = 'NULL' ;` ?

Comment: then null would be a string

Comment: Ah, right. You'd have to do something like: `$q = $_POST["qty".$z.$i];  if( $q == 0 || $q == "") { ${'qty'.$z} = NULL; } else {  ${'qty'.$z} = "'$q'"; }` and remove the single quotes from the UPDATE statement. But you **must also** escape the `$q` parameter before passing it to the database engine. Or better yet, **use prepared statements**. What database engine are you using?

Comment: cpanel has phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, instead of using

```
$priceupdate = $conn ->query("UPDATE table SET qty1 = '$qty1',  qty2 = '$qty2',  qty3 = '$qty3',  qty4 = '$qty4', qty5 = '$qty5',  qty6 = '$qty6' WHERE id = '$id'"); 
if($priceupdate ->execute()){ do something }
```

I used with prepare like this

```
 $priceupdate = $conn ->query("UPDATE table SET qty1 = ?,  qty2 = ?,  qty3 = ?,  qty4 = ?, qty5 = ?,  qty6 = ? WHERE id = ?");
$a = $priceupdate->execute(array($qty1, $qty2, ..., $id));
```

And it seems to be working, this way NULL doesn't become a string for sure.